# While loop in cursor not working properly

Tags: postgresql

I tried storing the result in a varable and use coalece.
But it is not working.

```
do
$$
declare
v_deptno numeric := 10;
stored_empno numeric;
curempno cursor is select empno from emp e where e.deptno = v_deptno;
recempno record;
begin   
open curempno;
fetch curempno
into recempno;
while found
loop
fetch curempno into recempno;
stored_empno:=recProdTest.empno;
raise info 'empno = %',coalesce(recProdTest.empno, stored_empno);
end loop;
close curempno;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a (slow and inefficient) cursor at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your program logic is wrong, and that won't work in Oracle either.

How many `FETCH` statements are executed before the first `RAISE`? Exactly, two: one before the loop, one in the loop.

So you are skipping the first result. The final `NULL` is because you don't check `FOUND` between `FETCH` and `RAISE`, so you report the empty result you get because the cursor is done.

Try a loop like this:

```
OPEN curempno;
LOOP
   FETCH curempno INTO recempno;
   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
   RAISE INFO 'empno = %', recempno.empno;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have used as you suggested but its giving the output 7839,7782,7934. The empno 7839 should not come in the output. I need the output same as in Oracle. Please help me.

Comment: If you want bug-for-bug compatibility with your Oracle code, re-add the extra `FETCH` in the beginning, store the last `empno` you got in a variable and use `coalesce(recempno.empno, stored_empno)`.

Comment: I added the extra FETCH in the beginning tried storing the result in a varable and use coalece.
But it is not working.

I have editted my post. Please help me.

Comment: `stored_empno:=recProdTest.empno;` should be moved up, just after the `loop`. But that whole code makes no sense at all.